# Attempting Apps Script/Google Sheets to find a certain row, then add values (from other cells) to columns in that row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

building a dashboard/tool to collect some very unique data (I've made an example sheet with straightforward info in it for clarity).

Say I want to give it to someone counting the cars entering (in), exiting (out), and parked around a parking garage. The dashboard will have the current count of vehicles spotted and only shows the vehicles that have actually been tallied; if all three columns (in, out, parked) are 0, they won't be shown on the dashboard.

The quick add/subtract area also on the dashboard should have 4 drop downs, one pulling from a named list on the helper sheet of all the possible vehicles being tallied, and then three dropdowns with numbers. Two buttons are next to it one for ADD and the other SUBTRACT.

The functionality I'm trying to achieve is when you pick a vehicle from the quick add/subtract and then select 2 in the "IN" dropdown, it needs to go to the helper sheet, find the row with the correct vehicle and in the IN column, add two. Similar on the subtract button, but I think I want to avoid having a negative number.

The big question is, is this something Apps Script can do in the first place? I think it is, and I've tried experimenting with the functions available but I can't work it out.

If any of that is confusing, hopefully the example I put together will help clarify:

[Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_ZjBuu8vrqOyRa3eYZmL-gq01u0RVycvgwLEhbEuiWU/edit?usp=sharing)

[Screenshot of Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vR6b6.png)

Comment: Is your goal to add or subtract the 3 numbers IN, OUT, PARK to Helper and then also populate the results of the addition/subtraction to Dashboard on the left?  And if a car that had no values gets a value show in the same order as on Helper?

Comment: Yes, On the dashboard the list to the left is a query looking at the list on the helper sheet and returning only cars that have been tallied.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Description**

There are 2 parts to this question.

Fist a simple QUERY in cell A1 of Dashboard will give the Tally `=QUERY(TallyList,"where B+C+D > 0")`

And second a script for each button to add or subtract the values to the tally.  The script `addButton` need to be assigned to the Add Button and `subtractButton` assigned to the Subtract Button.

**Code.gs**

```
function addButton() {
  doTheMath(true);
}

function subtractButton() {
  doTheMath(false);
}

function doTheMath(plus) {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let dash = spread.getSheetByName("Dashboard");
    // get tally count
    let tally = dash.getRange(3,6,1,4).getValues(); // F3:I3
    let helper = spread.getSheetByName("Helper Static List");
    // get TallyList values
    let tallyList = helper.getRange("TallyList").getValues();
    // find the car in TallyList
    let carIndex = tallyList.findIndex( row => row[0] === tally[0][0] );
    let car = tallyList[carIndex];
    // increment the count inplace
    car.forEach( (count,index,car) => { if( index > 0 ) { car[index] = plus ? count+tally[0][index] : count-tally[0][index] } } );
    // now put car count back into TallyList, need to add 1 to carIndex
    helper.getRange(carIndex+1,1,1,car.length).setValues([car]);
  }
  catch(err) {
    //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(err);
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Reference**

- [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [Array.findIndex()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_findindex.asp)
- [Array.forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)
- [Assign script to button](https://spreadsheet.dev/buttons-in-google-sheets#:%7E:text=Select%20the%20button%20and%20select,to%20run%20and%20select%20OK.)